# Training Examples used in Stochastic Gradient Descent

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent

Hi I was reading the difference between GD and SGD and found the below link.

[[What is the difference between Gradient Descent and Stochastic Gradient Descent?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/36450/what-is-the-difference-between-gradient-descent-and-stochastic-gradient-descent?newreg=d0824e455dd849b48ae833f5829d4fb5][1])

Based on this information I wanted to understand how would SGD train in the below scenario :

Say we have a dataset having 10000 rows and 45 predictors. Now, since SGD trains each predictor on one example(1 from 10000) , does that mean it uses only 45 examples in total to train the 45 predictors?

I'd really appreciate a clear explanation of this scenario.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In a given iteration of the stochastic gradient descent algorithm, all 45 predictors are updated using a randomly generated subset of your 10,000 observation sample.  This subset may consist of only 1 observation, but typically cross validation is used to determine the optimal subset size.  You could even try randomly generating different subset sizes each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Each stochastic gradient descent step would update the 45 model parameters using one training example.

Mathematically the gradient step in SGD can be represented as-

[image]

References-

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent